# Is localStorage safe? Can I access it from another app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am making a jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap app.

I am about to save some data to local storage. I am wondering if it is safe on mobile browsers (Android, iOS and windows). On PC I am able to check the values in FireBug. Is it possible somehow on mobile devices? Can I access in app A data specified by app B?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's possible too. Don't store anything in there you wouldn't be comfortable with other people seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in iOS, if it's a phonegap app the localStorage is only accesible from the app.

To check values while you are developing, you can try [debug phonegap](http://debug.phonegap.com/).(only works on webkit browsers). If you put a name there, it creates a script tag to include in your index. If you include that script tag in your index and execute the app you can see a remote web inspector for your app.